# SQL query for allocation of managers fulfilling given criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of sellers and i have to allocated them managers. The data format is as below

```
Seller  category    Division    Sales 
David     17          A          5000
David     23          B          2000
David     91          C          100
David     25          C          200
Jack      23          A          4000
Jack      17          A          4000
Jack      25          B          3000
```

Now the list of managers is provided as below:

```
Manager preferred_category  Designation
Tom           17               H
Aman          17               L
Sandy         23               H
John          23               L
Robin         91               H
Adam          91               L
Clara         25               H
Ted           25               L
```

Now the rules followed will be as below:

1. Sellers A and B division categories will be allotted to the desig 'H' manager of that category, and C category will get the the same from its A, B managers of the category with highest sales

   2. If all division are C, then the seller will get only 1 manager, the L desig of the category with highest sales for the seller

I have managed to work it out in VBA but it is too much hassle in that and i want to automate in sql. I need to only find some kind of starting or way to start the process, i will be able to take that forward. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: could you please upvote or accept my answer in recognition of time spent? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough approach. Not guaranteed to work on any particular SQL flavour but I assume you have Access or SQL Server.

1. create two tables, SELLER and MANAGER and insert your data
2. on the SELLER table, add an Autonumber column called "seller_id", and a new integer column called "manager_id" (with no data yet)
3. on the MANAGER table, add an Autonumber column called "manager_id" as well
4. do some SQL to populate the SELLER.manager_id column:

Something like this for rule 1:

```
update seller set manager_id = 
   (select manager_id from MANAGER m 
    inner join SELLER s on s.category = m.preferred_category
    where s.division in ('A','B') and m.designation = 'H' 
    and rownum < 2)
```

And for rule 2:

```
update seller set manager_id = 
   (select manager_id from MANAGER m 
    inner join SELLER s on s.category = m.preferred_category
    where s.division = 'C' and m.designation = 'L' 
    and rownum < 2)
```

If you need to allocate more managers to sellers you'll need to create a cross-reference table and move the ID columns around

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think then i have to run some kind of loop to get multiple sellers allocated to multiple managers

Comment: In that case you'll need a cross-reference table, e.g. `SELLER_MANAGER_ALLOC`,  populated as follows: `select s.seller_id, m.manager_id into SELLER_MANAGER_ALLOC from MANAGER m inner join SELLER s on s.category = m.preferred_category where s.division in ('A','B') and m.designation = 'H' `